# How to get greatest time when there is an aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| id | type | score |  unix_time  |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| 1  | 1    | 5     | 1463508841  |  -- this (current output)
| 2  | 1    | 10    | 1463508842  |
| 3  | 2    | 5     | 1463508843  |  -- this (current output)
| 4  | 1    | 5     | 1463508844  |
| 5  | 2    | 15    | 1463508845  |  -- this (expected output)
| 6  | 1    | 10    | 1463508846  |  -- this (expected output)
+----+------+-------+-------------+
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(score), unix_time
FROM mytable
WHERE 1
GROUP BY type
```

And this is **current output:**

```
+-------+-------------+
| score |  unix_time  |
+-------+-------------+
| 30    | 1463508841  |
| 20    | 1463508843  |
+-------+-------------+
```

As you see, the output is containing the first row's `unix_time`. But I'm trying to select greatest one.

So here is **expected output:**

```
+-------+-------------+
| score |  unix_time  |
+-------+-------------+
| 30    | 1463508846  |
| 20    | 1463508845  |
+-------+-------------+
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need sum(score) and max(unix_time) for the grouped value

```
SELECT type, SUM(score), max(unix_time)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY type
```

I omitted where 1 because seems non sense ..

Comment: May you please tell me should I write `unix_time` into `GROUP BY` too?

Comment: Just for my curiosity .. but why do you need unit_time in group by .. ?

Comment: You don't need because unix_time is argument of aggregate function max(..)  then .. you don't need this column in group by ...

Comment: Ok, suppose there isn't `MAX()` function, so do I need to write it into `GROUP BY`?

Comment: If you don't have max(unix_time)  .. but you want select unix_time then you must add this column to group by .. the same for all other column you want in select but that are not argument of a aggregate function .. eg: if you want select id and sum(score) you must add id in group by clause .. this becuase aggregate function  level and not aggregate column must  macth  by group by clause ... hope my argument are clear to you

Comment: Your argument is pretty clear for me and thx .. Just I completely disagree `:-)` Because if I write `id` into `GROUP BY` the result will be made of a lot of extra rows which are useless ...

Comment: Why you are disagree .? .. is normal relation db theory .. this is the base of groupin and aggegate function

Comment: Yes I heard that already .. But It isn't reasonable for me at all. `id` is an unique column, so if I write it into `GROUP BY` then each row will be a separated group and nothing get sum .. Or maybe I didn't understand how `GROUP BY` works ..

Comment: You haven't understand group by .. .. if you use a column with different value for each row and perform a group by on this column you don't get any aggregate function because the aggregation i broken for every row .. you use for group by the column type that in your sample has 3 rows (each in this case)  your aggregation then  sum the value (or select the max) based on the equal type value for each type value ..

Answer (score 1):

Get the max time and total for each type and `join` on type.

```
select tm.maxtime,tot.total
from (select max(unixtime) maxtime, type
     from mytable 
     group by type) tm
join (SELECT SUM(score) total, type
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY type) tot
on tot.type = tm.type
```

or simply

```
select max(unixtime) maxtime, sum(score) total
from mytable 
group by type
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `max()`:

```
SELECT SUM(score), MAX(unix_time)
FROM mytable
WHERE 1
GROUP BY type;
```

MySQL is pretty much the only database that accepts your version of the query.  You should be getting an error, because `unix_time` is not in the `GROUP BY` and not an argument to an aggregation function.

Comment: If I use `unix_time` into `GROUP BY`, nothing get sum. Because all rows will be unique ..! Thx anyway +1

Comment: Also `id` is  not in the `GROUP BY` and not an argument to a an aggregation function too .. So why you don't care about that?

Comment: @Shafizadeh `id` is not in the `SELECT`.